# @MessageMapping with placeholders

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am working with Spring-websocket and I have the following problem:

I am trying to put a placeholder inside a `@MessageMapping` annotation in order to get the url from properties. It works with `@RequestMapping` but not with `@MessageMapping`.

If I use this placeholder, the URL is null. Any idea or suggestion?

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "${myProperty}")

@MessageMapping("${myProperty}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rossen Stoyanchev added placeholder support for @MessageMapping and @SubscribeMapping methods.

See Jira issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13271

Answer (score 1):

Spring allows you to use property placeholders in [`@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html), but not in [`@MessageMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/MessageMapping.html). This is 'cause the `MessageHandler`. So, we need to override the default `MessageHandler` to do this.

[`WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.html) does not support placeholders and you need add this support yourself.

For simplicity I just created another `WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler` class in my project at the same package of the original, `org.springframework.web.socket.messaging`, and override `getMappingForMethod` method from `SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler` with same content, changing only how `SimpMessageMappingInfo` is contructed using this with this methods (`private` in `WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler`):

```
private SimpMessageMappingInfo createMessageMappingCondition(final MessageMapping annotation) {
    return new SimpMessageMappingInfo(SimpMessageTypeMessageCondition.MESSAGE, new DestinationPatternsMessageCondition(
            this.resolveAnnotationValues(annotation.value()), this.getPathMatcher()));
}

private SimpMessageMappingInfo createSubscribeCondition(final SubscribeMapping annotation) {
    final SimpMessageTypeMessageCondition messageTypeMessageCondition = SimpMessageTypeMessageCondition.SUBSCRIBE;
    return new SimpMessageMappingInfo(messageTypeMessageCondition, new DestinationPatternsMessageCondition(
            this.resolveAnnotationValues(annotation.value()), this.getPathMatcher()));
}
```

These methods now will resolve value considering properties (calling `resolveAnnotationValues` method), so we need use something like this:

```
private String[] resolveAnnotationValues(final String[] destinationNames) {
    final int length = destinationNames.length;
    final String[] result = new String[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = this.resolveAnnotationValue(destinationNames[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

private String resolveAnnotationValue(final String name) {
    if (!(this.getApplicationContext() instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext)) {
        return name;
    }

    final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) this.getApplicationContext();
    final ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = applicationContext.getBeanFactory();

    final String placeholdersResolved = configurableBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(name);
    final BeanExpressionResolver exprResolver = configurableBeanFactory.getBeanExpressionResolver();
    if (exprResolver == null) {
        return name;
    }
    final Object result = exprResolver.evaluate(placeholdersResolved, new BeanExpressionContext(configurableBeanFactory, null));
    return result != null ? result.toString() : name;
}
```

You still need to define a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean in your configuration.

If you are using XML based configuration, include something like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/META-INF/spring/url-mapping-config.properties" />
```

If you are using Java based configuration, you can try in this way:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = @PropertySource("classpath:/META-INF/spring/url-mapping-config.properties"))
public class URLMappingConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

**Obs.**: in this case, `url-mapping-config.properties` file are in a gradle/maven project in `src\main\resources\META-INF\spring` folder and content look like this:

```
myPropertyWS=urlvaluews
```

This is my sample controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @SendTo("/topic/test")
    @MessageMapping("${myPropertyWS}")
    public String test() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(4000); // simulated delay
        return "OK";
    }

}
```

With default `MessageHandler` startup log will print something like this:

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/${myPropertyWS}],messageType=[MESSAGE]}" onto public java.lang.String com.brunocesar.controller.WebSocketController.test() throws java.lang.Exception
```

And with our `MessageHandler` now print this:

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/urlvaluews],messageType=[MESSAGE]}" onto public java.lang.String com.brunocesar.controller.WebSocketController.test() throws java.lang.Exception
```

See in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/brunocesarsilva/d23dfbbf0f8479b6e6e9) the full `WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler` implementation.

**EDIT:** this solution resolves the problem for versions before `4.2 GA`. For more information, see [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13271) jira.

Comment: It works for @requedtmapping, but did you try this for @Messagemapping?

Comment: @bruno_cesar you scared me with first your answer :P

I was trying with 4.2.0.RC1 for last one hour :P

Comment: @karthik yeah, sorry :P

Comment: no issues :) (don't mind this part, I am just making the comment 15 characters :P)

Comment: Hi Bruno, I added an issue in Jira and they have included the improvement for 4.2. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

**Update** :

Now I understood what you mean, but I think that is not possible(yet).

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/MessageMapping.html) does not mention anything related to Path mapping URIs.

[image]

**Old answer**

Use

```
   @MessageMapping("/handler/{myProperty}")
```

instead of

```
   @MessageMapping("/handler/${myProperty}")
```

And use it like this:

```
   @MessageMapping("/myHandler/{username}")
   public void handleTextMessage(@DestinationVariable String username,Message message) {
        //do something
   }
```

Comment: This not sets the URL, this is just for pass a parameter. I would like to indicate the URL by properties, I mean ${myProperty} indicates the complete URL

Answer (score -1):

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/{roomId}")
public Message handleMessages(@DestinationVariable("roomId") String roomId, @Payload Message message, Traveler traveler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Message received for room: " + roomId);
    System.out.println("User: " + traveler.toString());

    // store message in database
    message.setAuthor(traveler);
    message.setChatRoomId(Integer.parseInt(roomId));
    int id = MessageRepository.getInstance().save(message);
    message.setId(id);

    return message;
}
```